# Cannot Implement SearchView

Tags: java, android, xml, searchview

I do not know if it has to do with my theme or any app setting, but I cannot seem to implement the SearchView and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have tried countless times and have compared the rendering on different API's, but I cannot seem to get it to work:

**menu_search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fanpolls="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/hint_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    />
```

**New Image Activity**

```
public class NewImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SearchView mSearchView;
private RecyclerView mImageResults;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mImageResultsAdapter;
private ArrayList<Flicker> mPhotoArray;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_image);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    // Retrieve the SearchView and plug it into SearchManager
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchItem.expandActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

**Manifest**

```
            <application
    android:name=".FanPollsApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/fan_polls_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> <!-- ADD THIS LINE -->

    <activity
        android:name=".SignupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.firebase.ui.GoogleClientId"
        android:value="@string/google_client_id" />

    <activity android:name="com.firebase.ui.auth.twitter.TwitterPromptActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.firebase.ui.TwitterKey"
        android:value="@string/twitter_app_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.firebase.ui.TwitterSecret"
        android:value="@string/twitter_app_secret" />

    <activity
        android:name=".PollActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_poll"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoadingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".CreateActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NewImageActivity"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Are you using a Theme with no actionbar?

Comment: I have not declared a theme for this activity in my manifest, what's frustrating is that in another Android Studio file I can get it to work with the same code.

Comment: Is it due to my theme at the App Level being AppTheme.NoAcitonBar?

Comment: Probably... You could try adding a Toolbar to your Layout or changing the theme. Up to you